# Python / tkinter: horizontal scrollbar not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling, horizontal-scaling

I have a problem using a horizontal `tk.Scrollbar` on a `tk.Text` widget. It is displayed too small for the region it is supposed to scroll - if I move it to the left, it reaches the end of the scrollable region before the small bar touches the right side, as you'd expect. Also, if I let it go it visually jumps back to its original position at the start, the scroll state is not altered though.

What's weird is that I'm using the exact same syntax for the vertical scrollbar and it works flawlessly.

I included how I'm (ab)using the `tk.Text`-widget, which is `tk.Label`-widgets embedded into the `tk.Text`-widget via the `window_create` method.

Screenshots:

[image: wrong size]
[image: not scrolled all the way to the right]

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NW')

        # widget definitions
        cellYScrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical")
        cellXScrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal")
        full_width = 30
        self.cell = tk.Text(
            self, yscrollcommand=cellYScrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=cellXScrollbar.set,
            width=full_width, height=full_width / 2, wrap="none",
            cursor="arrow"
        )
        cellYScrollbar.config(command=self.cell.yview)
        cellXScrollbar.config(command=self.cell.xview)

        # widget gridding
        self.cell.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NW', padx=[5, 0], pady=[5, 0])
        cellXScrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='NEW', padx=[5, 0], pady=[0, 5])
        cellYScrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='NSW', padx=[0, 5], pady=[5, 0])

        tiles = []
        for i in range(0, 9):
            for j in range(0, 9):
                test = tk.Label(self.cell, text='TEST'+str(i)+str(j), width=7, height=3)
                tiles.append(test)
                self.cell.window_create("end", window=test, padx=1, pady=1)
            self.cell.insert("end", "\n")

        for tile in tiles:
            tile.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda event: self.cell.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units"))
        self.cell.config(state='disabled')


root = app()
root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: fixed the code, `.set` was missing in `xscrollcommand=cellXScrollbar.set`, thank you to acw1668!

Comment: `xscrollcommand=cellXScrollbar` should be `xscrollcommand=cellXScrollbar.set`.

Comment: yesssss thank you that should have been obvious, excellent!